# Skype with webcam work on Lenovo T450s running Ubuntu?

Tags: webcam

What is the current status of webcam support for Lenovo T450s?  In particular using the webcam for video chat apps such as Skype?  There are several posts from 2015 claiming webcam support was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 on a T450s and have no problem with the webcam.

I was on Ubuntu 14.10 at first, but had problems with my docking station so I upgraded to 15.04 with latest kernel and that solved most of them. I never had problems with my webcam though.

Comment: Dear jiboutin, have you used the webcam on your T450s for videoconferencing, or something else?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: videoconferencing